# variables and functions exercise with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Please bear with me. I am teaching myself JavaScript from CodeAcademy. I think I may need help because I am stuck.

So just a background, I am now learning functions. The goal of the exercises is to return the correct response for a given input. I think it would be best if I would let you see the code

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours){
    if (numHours>=8){
        return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
    }
    else{
        return "Get some more shut eye";
    }
}
sleepCheck(10);
sleepCheck(5);
sleepCheck(8);
```

So that is my code. My problem is that, the code would not return the correct response for the last two inputs. Can somebody help me, please? Just a little hint will be appreciated.

Here is the error from CodeAcademy:

> "Oops, try again. It looks like your function doesn't return "Get some more shut eye!" when numHours is 5. Check your if / else syntax and whether you're using the correct comparison operator."

Comment: I think it works fine : ) – maybe you could let us know what the "correct" output is, and what you are seeing

Comment: It works ! http://jsbin.com/bigepof/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: We can't read your mind. Describe in detail what you expected to happen and what happened instead.

Comment: but codeacademy won't let me pass.. which is so sad.

Comment: We don't know what the CodeAcademy requirements are for this exercise.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to print it or something? You're just returning and immediately discarding the value.

Comment: Here is the error from codeacademy. "Oops, try again. It looks like your function doesn't return "Get some more shut eye!" when numHours is 5. Check your if / else syntax and whether you're using the correct comparison operator."

Comment: Your string is missing the `!` at the end.

Comment: @gelolopez: Edit your question to add that information.

Comment: @Pointy you are a life saver!!!!! Thank you!!. If you want to put it as an answer, I'll accept immediately